# Moving Images when Page Scrolls up or down

Tags: jquery, scroll

hope you are doing well. 
As always, any help is much appreciated.

Am trying to figure out how to move images up or down with page scroll.

Code:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="imagecontainer">
<img src="https://placehold.it/150x150" alt="" />
</div>
<div class="imagecontainer">
<img src="https://placehold.it/150x150" alt="" />
</div>
<div class="imagecontainer">
<img src="https://placehold.it/150x150" alt="" />
</div>
<div class="imagecontainer">
<img src="https://placehold.it/150x150" alt="" />
</div>
<div class="imagecontainer">
<img src="https://placehold.it/150x150" alt="" />
</div>
<div class="imagecontainer">
<img src="https://placehold.it/150x150" alt="" />
</div>
<div class="imagecontainer">
<img src="https://placehold.it/150x150" alt="" />
</div>
</div>
```

When you scroll down (the page) the images would move to a max of say 10px, and you scroll up, they return to the original position. the images need to move AS the scroll happens.

I have tried using $(window).scroll with animate but the images only move "once"

here is the pen
http://codepen.io/_Dawood/pen/aWZNVo

Comment: I think I have found a "working" solution if anyone wants to look at the codepen :)

Answer (score 0):

You can animate images or `div` which this code.

Its not a one-time animation. It animates looking for the current scroll position.

**Code snippet: Scrolling with position**

```js
var container = document.getElementById('container');
var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
var windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
var scrollArea = 1000 - windowHeight;
var image1 = document.getElementsByClassName('image')[0];
var image2 = document.getElementsByClassName('image')[1];

window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  var scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || window.scrollTop;
  var scrollPercent = scrollTop/scrollArea || 0;
  
  image1.style.bottom = scrollPercent*window.innerWidth + 'px';
  image2.style.right = scrollPercent*window.innerWidth + 'px';
});
```

```css
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
}

.image {
  position: absolute;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="imagecontainer">
    <img class="image" src="https://placehold.it/150x150" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="imagecontainer">
    <img class="image" src="https://placehold.it/150x150" alt="" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the help! it's not quite what am looking for. I had seen that on codepen but it didnt work they way i needed

Comment: would be nice if you can upvote and accept this answer for the help:)

Comment: feel free to ask more!

Comment: Why should they accept and upvote? They have clearly stated it wasn't what they were looking for.